# Clibboard exchange not working in VMware player 5

Tags: vmware-player

I have a Kubuntu 12.10 64bit as host and CentOS 6 32bit as guest system on VMware player 5 on a Dell Latitude E6510.
Despite the installation of VMware tools, the clipboard exchange is not working.

I use a very similar guest system within VirtualBox and there cliboard exchange works fine.

Has someone experienced the same with a configuration similar to mine?
And is it possible, that the guest system causes the problem instead of the player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having installed several constellations like that, I experienced, that in general it works, I can exchange the clipboard in both ways and even the desktop size adapts to the size of the VM window, but still from time to time having a situation, where it doesn't work and also heard of many other people who experienced that.

So, if someone can enlighten me on that point, I'll be happy, but I'm closing my question hereby.

Answer (score 3):

I've found thaht suspending and then re-playing the VM will re-enable clipboard exchange. 
Clipboard exchange will then work both between VMs and the Host machine as well as between VMs themselves.
(VMWare Player 5.0, Windows 7)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Lately, I haven't experiences that problem, but it may be a good workaround.